# Soaui project creation by using wsdl

Tags: wsdl, soapui, project

I am Getting an error while creating sopaui project by using wsdl..[I have tried many times by changing wsdl,but,i am getting this type of error only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfqDP.png)

Comment: Could you help us by showing us the WSDL ?

Comment: Error loading [http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?wsdl, 0

Comment: i changed that proxy settings into null,but,still i am getting the same error

Comment: It works on my side, SoapUI 5.3.
I'd say that it's an error related to your network or to your soapui network configuration.
If it's the first (network error), then trying the same outside your current network should confirm the issue.
If it's the second, you could try using SoapUI Standalone (to have default settings): https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-5.4.0-win32-standalone-bin.zip